# Hadoop hdfs vs ext3

Tags: hadoop, filesystems

I read in internet that ext3 file system is good to go while running hadoop.(http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/DiskSetup see end of page)

Then why we need hdfs

I assume hdfs is a filesystem similarly ext3 is another type of filesystem

please let me know how ext3 and hdfs works in hadoop?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

HDFS is distributed filesystem, which means that file is divided into more smaller parts and these parts are stored on different nodes/servers.

Particular node/server can use ext3 filesystem, which means that HDFS file part is physically stored on disk with ext3.